# Python import loops and top level program structure

Tags: python, design-patterns, import

So to help me learn Python I'm building a simple little text based game. I'm working on the rough highest level structure of the files. So far I have main.py, input.py and commands.py.

**main.py**

```
from input import *
x = 1
start()
```

**input.py**

```
from commands import *

def inputLoop():
    inString = input('::> ')
    tokens = inString.split(' ')
    cmd = tokens[0]
    args = tokens[1:]
    if cmd != '':
        try:
            commands[cmd](args)
        except KeyError:
            print('Command not found.')
        print('\n')
    inputLoop()

def start():
    inputLoop()
```

**commands.py**

```
def quit(arg):
    input('Goodbye!')
    exit()

def echo(arg):
    print(' '.join(arg))

commands = {
    'exit' : quit,
    'echo' : echo
}
```

As you can see main.py imports input.py, which imports commands.py. This all works great, I can map text input to functions effectively, and pass arguments successfully. What I'm having trouble with is the correct way to make variables declared in main.py accessible to the functions in commands.py. If I import main.py from commands.py, it creates an import loop. I know I'm missing some high level design pattern to hold this whole thing together.

Maybe I make a main class, an import class, and a commander class and pass the instance of the main class down through each constructor until the commander  class can reference it, but that seems cludgy and inelegant to me.

How would you structure this program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you separate your variables into a "settings.py" and import that whenever you want to access them.

Although i would prefer to manage them inside some class called Settings or Options, as a change to one might cascade into other settings...

Also if you access global variables inside a local scope (inside a function), then you have to declare them global.

```
s = 1
def func(x):
    global s
    s=2
```

otherwise you will just spawn a local variable called s

Comment: I was thinking more like instances of player and enemy classes that the commands will need access to, but that would work for that too. Thanks for the advice!